# Как правильно употреблять "по-"?

Tags: орфография

Вот всегда "зависаю" при написании "по-моему", "по случаю" и прочие слова с "по". В некоторых случаях так и хочется поставить "-". Объясните, пожалуйста, когда его нужно употреблять?

Comment: Не то,что я хотела,2 этому сайту,даже 1!!!

Comment: @Амина вы можете задать свой вопрос, где уточнить, что бы именно вы хотели.

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы кто-нибудь смог составить алгоритм принятия решения (ставить "по" с пробелом, "по" слитно, или "по" с дефисом)

Answer (score 1):

Наречия с приставкой по- пишутся через дефис, если оканчиваются на -ому, -му, -ки,-и: по-моему, по-видимому, по-волчьи, по-русски, по-латыни

Answer (score 1):

1. Приставка ПО в наречиях пишется слитно или через дефис. Дефисное написание регулируется  известным правилом, которое здесь уже названо, но наречия с дефисным написанием нужно отличать от наречий, в которых приставка ПО пишется СЛИТНО: А) ссориться поначалу, согласиться поневоле – от существительного начало, Б) продавать поштучно – от прилагательного штучный, В) идти потихоньку – от наречия тихонько, Г) остаться  подольше – от наречия дольше.
2. РАЗДЕЛЬНОЕ написание. 
    Наречия с приставкой ПО нужно отличать от наречных выражений и существительных  с предлогом ПО, где имеет место падежное управление: по старинке, не по нутру, по памяти, 
   НО: поистине, поначалу, поневоле (нет предложного управления).

ТАКЖЕ: А) расходиться по одному (предметное значение числительного, перешедшего в существительное), Б) получить отлично по латыни (по латинскому языку

1. Особую группу составляют ПРОСТРАНСТВЕННЫЕ наречия и существительные, которые часто встречаются в парных вариантах. Здесь выбор формы написания зависит от наличия зависимых слов, а также от  предметного или обстоятельственного значения:
   Не всюду пОверху пройдешь, ино и погрязнешь. Идут по верху ржаных полей темные волны ветра. Вагоны были окрашены по нИзу в кофейный цвет, а по вЕрху – в сливочный.